# Adding None Value Always gives 0

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to create a function that adds the numbers in the columns in a matrix and output a vector made of the sum. However if there is a "None" value in the matrix, the output vector gets a "None" value for that column automatically. I cannot figure out how to do the part for the "None" value.

I tried the following code.

```
def sum_matrix (matrix):
    #
    # | 1 2 3 |
    # | 1 2 3 |
    # | 1 2 3 |  ->  |4 8 12|
    # | 1 2 3 |
    # _________
    #   4 8 12
    vektor = [[0] for i in range(0,len(matrix[0]))]
    for j  in range(0, len(matrix[0])):        #rows 0-3 4
        buffer = 0
        for i in range(0, len(matrix)):  #columns 3
            if matrix[i][j] !=None:
                buffer = buffer + matrix[i][j]
                #vektor[j][0] = buffer
            elif matrix[i][j] ==None:
                vektor[j][0] = None
        vektor[j][0] = buffer 
    return vektor

print (sum_matrix ([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]))
print (sum_matrix ([[0,0,0],[0,None,1],[0,1,None],[0,0,0]]))
```

For `sum_matrix ([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])`, I get `[[0],[1],[1]]` which is good.
For sum_matrix `([[0,0,0],[0,None,1],[0,1,None],[0,0,0]])`, I still get `[[0],[1],[1]]` even though I am supposed to get `[[0],[None],[None]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I always say, you should differentiate a *matrix* (a mathematical abstraction) from its *implementation* (a `list` of `lists`).

Now, what we have here is basically a `list` of `lists` where each inner `list` represents a row, but we want to take the sum of each column, with the additional constraint that it should be `None` whenever it contains at least one `None` value.

The simplest way to do this, I would say, is using a `list` comprehension in conjunction with `zip`, which effectively transposes your matrix:

```
def sum_matrix(m):
    transposed = zip(*m)
    summed = [[sum(col) if None not in col else None] 
              for col in transposed]
    return summed

print(sum_matrix([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]))
print(sum_matrix([[0,0,0],[0,None,1],[0,1,None],[0,0,0]]))
```

Output:

```
[[0], [1], [1]]
[[0], [None], [None]]
```

Note: you can also couch the inner `list` comprehension as `[None if None in col else sum(col)]`, but I prefer to put the "normal" case first.

You could also convert `col` to a `set`, which allows constant time lookups, but actual conversion to a `set` is linear time, and since we're only iterating over each column once, I don't think it'll be faster.

Answer (score 0):

when matrix[i][j]==None you need to store in the buffer None, since you're changing the value of vektor when exiting the inner loop, so **the vektor will always take the value of the buffer**

```
def sum_matrix (matrix):
#
# | 1 2 3 |
# | 1 2 3 |
# | 1 2 3 |  ->  |4 8 12|
# | 1 2 3 |
# _________
#   4 8 12
vektor = [[0] for i in range(0,len(matrix[0]))]
for j  in range(0, len(matrix[0])):        #rows 0-3 4
    buffer = 0
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):  #columns 3
        if matrix[i][j] !=None:
            buffer = buffer + matrix[i][j]
            #vektor[j][0] = buffer
        elif matrix[i][j] ==None:
            buffer = None
            break
    vektor[j][0] = buffer 
return vektor
```